# Python Docx - Sections - Page Orientation

Tags: python, orientation, docx, python-docx

The following code tries to use `landscape` orientation, but the document is created as `potrait.` 
Can you suggest where the problem is?

```
from docx import Document
from docx.enum.section import WD_ORIENT

document = Document()

section = document.sections[-1]
section.orientation = WD_ORIENT.LANDSCAPE

document.add_heading('text')
document.save('demo.docx')
```

When I read the code back as XML

```
<w:document>
    <w:body>
       <w:p>
          <w:pPr>
             <w:pStyle w:val="Heading1"/>
          </w:pPr>
          <w:r>
              <w:t>TEXT</w:t>
          </w:r>
       </w:p>
       <w:sectPr w:rsidR="00FC693F" w:rsidRPr="0006063C" w:rsidSect="00034616">
           <w:pgSz w:w="12240" w:h="15840" w:orient="landscape"/>
           <w:pgMar w:top="1440" w:right="1800" w:bottom="1440" w:left="1800" w:header="720" w:footer="720" w:gutter="0"/>
           <w:cols w:space="720"/>
           <w:docGrid w:linePitch="360"/>
        </w:sectPr>
    </w:body>
 </w:document>
```

I don't know XML well by assume the section tags should come above the TEXT tags at the top rather than the bottom????

Comment: Can you elaborate on "but not working": what do you get?

Comment: Word document comes out in portrait

Comment: Which Python and OS are you using? When I try to run your code as is, I get `ImportError: cannot import name Document`:

> $ cat stackoverflow1.py
>
> from docx import Document
> from docx.enum.section import WD_ORIENT
>
> document = Document()
>
> section = document.sections[-1]
> section.orientation = WD_ORIENT.LANDSCAPE
>
> document.add_heading('text')
> document.save('demo.docx')
>
> $ python stackoverflow1.py
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "stackoverflow1.py", line 1, in <module>
>     from docx import Document
> ImportError: cannot import name Document
>

Answer (score 19):

Whilst the page is correctly tagged as landscape, its dimensions remain the same as before and must be manually changed.

http://python-docx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/sections.html

> ## Page dimensions and orientation
>
> Three properties on Section describe page dimensions and orientation. Together these can be used, for example, to change the orientation of a section from portrait to landscape:

...

> `new_width, new_height = section.page_height, section.page_width
>   section.orientation = WD_ORIENT.LANDSCAPE
>   section.page_width = new_width
>   section.page_height = new_height`

Answer (score 7):

I have made a function that makes it easy to change from landscape orientation to portrait orientation and viceversa:

```
def change_orientation():
    current_section = document.sections[-1]
    new_width, new_height = current_section.page_height, current_section.page_width
    new_section = document.add_section(WD_SECTION.NEW_PAGE)
    new_section.orientation = WD_ORIENT.LANDSCAPE
    new_section.page_width = new_width
    new_section.page_height = new_height

    return new_section
```

Then just use it whenever you want:

```
change_orientation()
document.add_picture(ax1)
change_orientation()
document.add_picture(ax2)
```

Comment: Thanks, this was helpful. To make it work, I had to also add the command: 

From docx.enum.section import WD_ORIENT

Answer (score -3):

```
def change_orientation():
    current_section = document.sections[-1]
    new_width, new_height = current_section.page_height, current_section.page_width
    new_section = document.add_section(WD_SECTION_START.NEW_PAGE)
    new_section.orientation = WD_ORIENTATION.LANDSCAPE
    new_section.page_width = new_width
    new_section.page_height = new_height

    return new_section
```

new code !